# copy directory tar.gz file from root to external hard disk error

Tags: command-line, partitioning, hard-drive

I am able to login to root terminal and then create tar zip file by running the command `tar -zcvf dspace_tar.gz /home/dspace`  in  a root terminal.

But I am not able to copy using the command

```
cp -av dspace_tar.gz /dev/sdb1
```

which is my external hard disk.

I get two errors: `stat error` and `no such file or root directory.`

Comment: Please you should be doing `cp -av dspace_tar.gz /media/username/external_hdd_name`

Comment: Do `sudo lsblk -f` to see the address of the device when its plugged in.

Comment: @George I suggest writing an answer here

Comment: @Zanna done that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to write to a device file (`/dev/sdxY`) - you should write to the mount point (`/media/username/drive_name`)

Since your trying to copy as *root* you should be doing:

```
cp -av dspace_tar.gz /media/username/external_hdd_name
```

If you don't know the mount point of the device, first plug it in then do this to get the *address*:

```
lsblk -f
```

The options:

- `-f` option provided more information about the filesystems.
- `-a` : used when copying archives
- `-v` : displays the process in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

the command "man cp" states that cp copies files and directories. This is a file system based operation. You try to copy a file direct - without using a file system - so a device (/dev/sdb1). Here are some options to meet your needs:

```
1. make a file system on /dev/sdb1 and copy the file with cp, in the way you tried it alread:
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydisk1
cp -av dspace_tar.gz /mnt/mydisk1/
```

or

```
2. use tar to write the data direct to sdb1
tar czvf /dev/sdb1 dspace_tar.gz
```

there are also other options, but I think this are the 2 major ways. Usual way is to use a file system on a disk device.

Comment: Only when he is trying to format the HDD should he be doing `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1` doing that will destroy any data he has there

Comment: Bad idea. He has filed in the gas.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overwrite your hard drive. I frequently use similar commands to write images.

If your hard drive is mounted somewhere try copying your file to the mount point. To do that run the command `lsblk` and look at the right side of the output.

If it isn't mounted you will have to mount it by first creating a directory for the mount point, then running `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 <path to folder>`. (Replace  with the path to your folder). Then you can copy the file onto the hard drive, which appears as the folder.